# Google Apps Script - copy cells into a new sheet on condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having a spreadsheet with thousands of rows and some entries have "#N/A" in the first column as a result of a lookup. I want those **rows** to be copied **entirely** on a new sheet.

Example:

| ID | Other Data |
| --- | --- |
| #N/A | row1 |
| 123 | row2 |
| #N/A | row3 |
| #N/A | row4 |
| #N/A | row5 |
| 456 | row6 |

The new sheet should contain the rows with "#N/A" in the ID field

| ID | Other Data |
| --- | --- |
| #N/A | row1 |
| #N/A | row3 |
| #N/A | row4 |
| #N/A | row5 |

Answer (score 1):

Just use the FILTER formula:
=FILTER(A2:B100, A2:A100="#N/A")

Answer (score 1):

connect the sheets with a query, is how I would do it:

```
=query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ID",
"'SHEET 1'!A2:Z"),
"select * where Col1 = '#N/A'")
```

You'll have to ok the connection between the sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this sample code on how to filter data from sheet and write the to a new sheet using apps script

### Sample Code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Filter N/A', 'FilterNA')
      .addToUi();
}

function FilterNA(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet();

  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var newData = data.filter(row => ["ID","#N/A"].includes(row[0]));
  newSheet.getRange(1,1,newData.length,newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

### What it does?

1. Create a custom menu to trigger the copy function
2. Select the active sheet and create a new sheet using [insertSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheet)
3. Read the data in your source sheet using [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) and [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)
4. Filter the array using [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), in this example I created a list of strings that I want to filter ("ID" and "#N/A") then check if current row's column 1 is either ID or N/A using [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
5. Write the filtered data in the new sheet.

### Output:

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered some issues so i could update the answer accordingly, I only assumed that you want to copy the filtered data on a new sheet.